# Alpha blending using opencv with a black png on python

Tags: python, image, opencv, video, png

I'm trying to create a aplication with opencv that overlaps a glass on me face. However, when the video appears the glasses have a black on the alpha layer. Here is my code:

```
video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
anterior = 0
glasses = cv2.imread('Glasses_1.png')

def put_glasses(glasses,fc,x,y,w,h):

    face_width = w
    face_height = h

    glasses_width = int(face_width)
    glasses_height = int(face_height*0.32857)



    glasses = cv2.resize(glasses,(glasses_width,glasses_height))

    for i in range(glasses_height):
        for j in range(glasses_width):
            for k in range(3):
                if glasses[i][j][k]<235:

                    fc[y+i-int(-0.25*face_height)-1][x+j][k] = glasses[i][j][k]
    return fc

while True:
    if not video_capture.isOpened():
        print('Unable to load camera.')
        sleep(5)
        pass
    ret, frame = video_capture.read()
    if ret is True:
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    else:
        continue

    faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(
        gray,
        scaleFactor=1.1,
        minNeighbors=5,
        minSize=(40,40)
    )
    for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
        cv2.putText(frame,"Person Detected",(x,y),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,1,(0,0,255),2)
        frame = put_glasses(glasses, frame, x, y, w, h)
```

I will be very grateful if anyone could help.

Comment: First---just a general comment here, but you really never need to loop through numpy arrays like that. You can assign multiple values at once without looping and it will be much faster. WRT the question you asked, where are you doing anything with an alpha layer?

Comment: I will discard the alpha layer, I just want the "glasses" and nothing in between

Comment: https://pytech-solution.blogspot.com/2017/07/alphablending.html You can go through this blog for alpha blending of a ROI

Comment: https://pytech-solution.blogspot.com/2018/02/fast-pixel-processing-with-opencv-and.html For fast pixel accessing/modification, you can imporve speed by 100x

Answer (score 1):

You read the png in `bgr` format, not the `bgra` or unchanged format. Then I don't think your glass image in the program is shape of `(h,w,4)`. You should read with flag `cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED`.

`glasses = cv2.imread("xxx.png", cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)`

---

Maybe this link will help. [How do I clear a white background in OpenCV with c++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47386925/how-do-i-clear-a-white-background-in-opencv-with-c/47388731#47388731)

The bgra worm:

[image]

Blending:

[image]

Comment: I tried this, but don't worked, still with the black.

Comment: @LaviniaPaganini have you check your png channels? especially the alpha.

Comment: Ok, I verified. The mistake was on the image that I'm using :) Thank you